# Characteristic polynomial for A when $A=(a_{ij})$

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-functions, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $f(t)=(-1)^nt^n+b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1t+b_0$

Define $A=(a_{ij})$. Show that $f(t)=(a_{11}-t)(a_{22}-t)\cdots(a_{nn}-t)+q(t)$, where $\deg q(t)\le n-2$

I am not sure where to start this problem. What is $q(t)$ and where does it come from?

Also, how do I apply the definition of $A=(a_{ij})$?

Comment: What is the definition of the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: @md5 $det(A-\lambda I_n)=0$. I just don't know how that applies to the $A=(a_{ij})$

Comment: With your notations, the characteric polynomial of $A$ would be $f(t)=\det(A-tI_n)$. Note that the matrix $A-t I_n$  is like the matrix $A$, but with $-t$ everywhere on the diagonal. Now can you relate the factor $(a_{11}-t)(a_{22}-t)\ldots(a_{nn}-t)$ that is supposed to appear in the answer and the definition of the determinant of $A-t I_n$?

Comment: @md5 but what happens to all of the cases where $i\neq j$ in $a_{ij}$? The formula in the problem only uses $a_{ij}$ where $i=j$.

Comment: You're correct, that's why there is an additional factor $q(t)$. Note that $q(t)$ will depend on the coefficients of $A$. But at least you found one particular term in the expansion of the determinant, right?

Comment: @md5 I guess I don't understand the leap here. We go from $A=(a_{ij})$ to the characteristic polynomial in the problem. I get that for each $1\le i \le n$, $ a_{ii}=det(a_{ii}-tI_1) = det(a_{ii}-t) = a_{ii}-t$ but how do I get $q(t)$?

Comment: I don't really understand the formula you wrote in your last sentence. Let's say for $n=3$, what you have is: $$f(t)=\det \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}-t&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}-t&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}-t\end{bmatrix}$$ What are the different terms that will appear in the determinant?

Comment: @md5 The formula I tried to describe is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ when $A=(a_{ij})$. $A$ is a $1x1$ matrix because $a_{ij}$ is a single element. Therefore when we find the characteristic polynomial of $A$ it is equal to $det(a_{ij}-tI_1) = det(a_{ij}-t) = a_{ij}-t$. Does this thinking make sense? It gets me $(a_{11}-t)(a_{22}-t)\cdots(a_{nn}-t)$ but not the $q(t)$.

Comment: For me $(a_{ij})$ implicitly means $(a_{ij})_{1\le i\le n,1\le j\le n}$ (so $n\times n$ matrix, not $1\times 1$). $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix as you wrote in your original post.

Comment: @md5 That would make significantly more sense. Thank you

Comment: @md5 So I then expand along the top row and get $$(a_{11}-\lambda)det\begin{pmatrix} a_{22}-\lambda & \cdots & a_{2n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}-\lambda\\ \end{pmatrix} + \cdots(-1)^n(a_{1,n}) det\begin{pmatrix} a_{21} & a_{22}-\lambda & \cdots & \cdots & a_{2,n-1}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33-\lambda} &\cdots & a_{3,n-1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \cdots \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: @md5 How do I go from this to the function given?

Comment: I suggest you to look at the *definition* of the determinant instead (the one with a sum of $n!$ terms). What will be the term of the sum with highest degree in terms of $\lambda$ (or $t$, depending how you call it)?

Comment: @md5 Just want to confirm you are talking about Laplace's formula?

Comment: I don't know what Laplace's formula is. I'm talking about something like: $$\det(B)=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n} \epsilon(\sigma) b_{1\sigma(1)}\ldots b_{n\sigma(n)}$$ Have you seen something like that already?

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) this is also known as "Leibniz formula"